# Is a 775 Motor Powerful Enough For a DIY Water Pump

Tags: water, pump, electric-motor

I tried making a water pump with what I think is a 550 motor (I can't identify it by the model number), but failed to create enough suction. The top pictures show the diy water pump parts from the failed attempt. The cylinder houses the motor and the motor shaft goes through the turbine. Water is sucked in through the lid of the cylinder (top lid with hose attached) and water exits through a hole in the cylinder. Unfortunately, the cylinder only got a little moist. I have seen 550 motors act as water pumps online, but I'm willing to upgrade to a more powerful DC motor (775 motor?).

Since I'm trying to do my due diligence this time before ordering a motor, I'd appreciate any feedback on the type of motor I need. I'd like to use it to make a diy water pump with water entering from a hose of 50 to 100 feet. I don't need a lot of water pressure, just want to move water from inside a barrel to the toilet. Any idea if this is possible using a diy 12 Volt pump?

diy water pump parts[image]550 motor?[image]

Comment: This is a stunningly bad project to "DIY" on for anything other than amusement value. 12VDC water pumps are extant, inexpensive compared to doing it wrong a few times, and far more reliable than some hot-glued PVC mess. Your motor probably has more than enough power, were it attached to a decent pump. Building a decent pump is not a trivial project even if you have a machine shop available.

Comment: ok, the youtube videos i saw led me to believe otherwise. So what 12VDC motor water pump would you recommend for my application?

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those deals where it's actually a more efficient use of your time to say "would you like fries with that?" for a few hours and use the wage to buy that thing COTS.

Comment: Your pump design will not move fluid unless it is completely submerged in the fluid, i.e. it cannot pump air and cannot "suck" water up out of a container...

Comment: Try putting your water ouptut radially.

Comment: The obvious straightforward choice would be a pump from a "recreational vehicle" (camper van/trailer) water system application. Alternate choices could go down to a windshield washer pump if you don't mind a rather slow refill. Bilge pumps (boat store) if you'd like a very fast refill. A hand-powered pump if electricity is in short supply.

Comment: as @JimmyFix-it it says.  It wont work.  You could run a 15Kw motor and not get anywhere.  You need a Vacuum capable system to suck something 100 feet up a pipe.  Also, gluing together a motor and propeller is a bit dangerous.  If you get a jam, the motor will over heat.  Modern water pumps spin up the propeller on a magnet based system